# How to overwrite global Git credentials for one repo?

Tags: git, config, credentials

If I set

```
git config --global credential.username my_username
```

option, then overwriting it for one repository with `--local` option gives no difference for it - it still uses global credentials while trying to commit or push. How can I change this?

Comment: Are you sure the  `.git/config` file for the repository was updated?

Comment: @chepner yes, it contains `username` set with `--local` option

Comment: In cases like these I find it more convenient to just fire up an editor with `~/.gitconfig` and `myproject/.git/config`. Shows you precisely what options you have set, and the syntax is quite self explanatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repo local config doesn't work for me. After trying all kinds of ways from stackoverflow, finally it works by switching from ssh to https and using *credential.helper* :

**step 1**, change git remote from ssh to https:

```
$ git remote -v
    git@github.com:#####/###.git (push)

$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin https://username@github.com/######/###.git
```

**step 2**, let *credential.helper* to help remember password to avoid annoying repeat asking.

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

By default credentials will be saved in ~/.git-credentials. It will be created and written to.

**But please note** using this helper will **store your passwords unencrypted** on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions. If this may not be an acceptable security tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

> **[credential.username](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config)**
>
> If no username is set for a network authentication, use this username by default

Probably you have `user.name` configured on `--global`, so `credential.username` on `--local` is not used. Try this:

```
git config --local user.name my_username
```

Comment: This setting is used when commiting, but pushing still uses global credential setting.